# NumberFormatException: Invalid int:""

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, localization, numberformatexception, parseint

In my app, I am doing language localization.it works perfectly with buttons and texviews but cant change the string on the recyclerview

it says
**NumberFormatException: Invalid int:""**

```html
  private void updateViews(String languageCode) {
                Context context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, languageCode);
                Resources resources = context.getResources();
                changelang.setText(resources.getString(R.string.changelanguage));
                languagename.setText(resources.getString(R.string.languagename));
 //error with following line                  object01.setDepname(Integer.parseInt(resources.getString(R.string.cultivation)));

            }
        });
```

Stacktrace

```css
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "खेती"
                                                                                        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
                                                                                        at com.example.rimapps.icar_iisr_ginger.MainActivity$1.updateViews(MainActivity.java:125)
                                                                                        at com.example.rimapps.icar_iisr_ginger.MainActivity$1.access$000(MainActivity.java:92)
                                                                                        at com.example.rimapps.icar_iisr_ginger.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:101)
                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1044)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3081)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3947)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5523)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

please help

Comment: whats the value of `cultivation` in string file? Is it a number?

Comment: No text in Hindi language like as follows         <string name="cultivation">खेती</string>

Comment: then why you convert it to `int`?

Comment: I also tried to do that in string,can you please check my previous post

Comment: okay provide a link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442813/cant-update-recyclerview-text

Comment: see my answer hope it's helped you

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to convert an string from your resources to an integer value. This is not possible!
To support multiple languages create a new string.xml with your desired locale.

See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: I have created string .xmls for both languages and its working for button names and text views. but not for recycler view. so what should i do in this case, I have defined that text as int in my model class

Answer (score 0):

As You are trying to convert a string from your resources to an integer value. This is not possible, So Try to Change model class like this way

```
public class ContentsDep {
    int depimage;
    String depname;

    public int getDepimage() {return depimage;
    }

    public void setDepimage(int depimage) {this.depimage = depimage;
    }

    public void setDepname(String depname) {
        this.depname = depname;
    }

    public String getDepname() {return depname;}

}
```

Then Set value like this way

```
object01.setDepname(resources.getString(R.string.cultivation));
```

Comment: actually, bro, I have tried this before.but it arises a new problem

Comment: actually, bro, I have tried this before.but it arises a new problem  final ContentsDep object01 = new ContentsDep();
        object01.setDepname(R.string.varieties);//in this line it shows a "setDepname in contents cannot applied to int"  so i just did it to string,then i had to change it also in the adapter class.then after i executed it showing a long number instead of string name